# php rsort time difference between minutes

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to sort times to get the median, it works fine 
BUT... the minutes, if I have 01 Hour 2 minute it is ranked above 01 hour 15 minute

```
do {

$date1 = new DateTime($row_vdata['Actual Attend Date']);      
$date2 = new DateTime($row_vdata['Actual Perm Repair Date'])   
$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);
$responsetimes[$sum]=$diff->format('%H Hour %i Minute');
$sum = $sum + 1;

}while( $row_vdata = $vdata->fetch());

rsort($responsetimes);

foreach ($responsetimes as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

your help is much appreciated

Sample of results

```
0 = 23 Hour 30 Minute
1 = 22 Hour 55 Minute
2 = 22 Hour 0 Minute
3 = 21 Hour 6 Minute
4 = 21 Hour 40 Minute
5 = 20 Hour 45 Minute
...
```

What I would like

```
0 = 23 Hour 30 Minute
1 = 22 Hour 55 Minute
2 = 22 Hour 0 Minute
3 = 21 Hour 40 Minute
4 = 21 Hour 6 Minute
5 = 20 Hour 45 Minute
...
```

Comment: Your test data? Why don't you compare the DateTime objects directly, or the DateDiff objects.

Comment: Too many unknowns: 1) What is your expected output? 2) Where does `$sum` come from ?

Comment: I addmitted code, for simplicity assume $sum is set to zero before code

Comment: Please add a little example to reproduce your scenario and explain what output you get now. And what you would expect to get ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving your formatted date into your array better save just the hours and minutes, so it is easier to sort your array and if you want to print your array, you can format the date as you want, e.g.

```
do {

    $date1 = new DateTime($row_vdata['Actual Attend Date']);      
    $date2 = new DateTime($row_vdata['Actual Perm Repair Date'])   
    $diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);
    $responsetimes[$sum] = $diff->format("%H:%i");
    $sum++;

} while($row_vdata = $vdata->fetch());


usort($responsetimes, function($a, $b){
    if(strtotime($a) == strtotime($b))
        return 0;
    return strtotime($a) < strtotime($b) ? 1 : -1;
});

foreach ($responsetimes as $key => $val) {
    echo $x++ . " ";
    echo $key . " = " . date("H \H\o\u\\r i \M\i\\n\u\\t\\e", strtotime($val)) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: strtotime is definentaly the answer I required. Thank you